# Getting Warning in wordpress plugin post-my-contact-form-7 after updating to the PHP 7.2.0

Tags: php, wordpress

I am Working on a wordpress project it's working fine

When i Update the **PHP version 7.2.0** I am getting warning like this:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant WP_GURUS_DEBUG - assumed
>   'WP_GURUS_DEBUG' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\wordpress1\wp-content\plugins\post-my-contact-form-7\includes\wordpress-gurus-debug-api.php
>   on line 9

My wordpress version is **4.9.1**

My plugin:

> Post My CF7 Form
>   **Version 3.2.0**

Here is the plugin file:

```
<?php
/**
* Error logging and notices
* @since 1.0.0
* @var string $message to log if in debug mode
*/

if( !function_exists('debug_msg') ){
  if (true === WP_DEBUG || true === WP_GURUS_DEBUG) {
     $debug_msg_last_line='';
     $debug_msg_last_file='';
   }
  function debug_msg($message,$prefix='') {
      if (true === WP_DEBUG || true === WP_GURUS_DEBUG) {
        global $debug_msg_last_line,$debug_msg_last_file;
          $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
          $file = $backtrace[0]['file'];
          $files = explode('/',$file);
          $dirs = explode('/',plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ));
          $files = array_diff($files,$dirs);
          $file = implode('/',$files);
          $line = $backtrace[0]['line'];
          if($file != $debug_msg_last_file && $line != $debug_msg_last_line){
            error_log("DEBUG_MSG: [".$line."]./".$file);
            $debug_msg_last_file=$file;
            $debug_msg_last_line=$line;
          }else{
            //error_log("CF7_2_POST: ");
          }
          if (is_array($message) || is_object($message)) {
              error_log("          + ".$prefix.print_r($message, true));
          } else {
              error_log("          + ".$prefix.$message);
          }
      }
  }
} ?>
```

How to resolve this warning?

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: I informed the plugin maintainer, and this issue should now be resolved simply by updating the plugin.

> Aurovrata Venet wrote:
>
> oops, my bad!  Fixed in v3.2.1
>
> Post Link:
>   https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-use-of-undefined-constant-wp_gurus_debug/#post-9777594

---

`WP_DEBUG` is already [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) (as `false`, by default), but `WP_GURUS_DEBUG` apparently isn't defined by the plugin by default. Attempting to use an undefined constant will be considered an error in future versions of PHP, but as a heads-up they are displaying it as a warning to give developers a chance to update their code.

The plugin maintainers need to update line

`if (true === WP_DEBUG || true === WP_GURUS_DEBUG) {`

to check if the constants are [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) with something like:

`if ( ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) AND true === WP_DEBUG ) || ( defined( 'WP_GURUS_DEBUG' ) AND true === WP_GURUS_DEBUG ) ) {`

Comment: yep that's a bug alright, this is now fixed in v3.2.1!